# Store user data and allow users to add data from a public list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making an app wich allows users to get weatherdata from several sources at specific locations.

The problem i am facing is that pr. now when a user uses my app he/she will see all the location objects in the firebase database.  (Im planning to add login via firebase , login will be needed for this feature)

How can i easily store the users choosen locations in the app ?

For example : 
I would like to have a List of Locations Y, Z, X and so on. (Each with their own set of data,updated by the users)

User A wants to see Location Y and Z, User B wants to see Location Y and X

How should i store a link to the locations that user A wants to see ? and then be able to show those locations in a RecycleView.

Preferably i would also like that if user C joins he can add his own location or choose from a list of locations.

Comment: If there is no login, how do you know which is the current user? A, B or C?

Comment: Good point, im planning to add a login, will add that to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using Firebase Database, store the User's preferenes on that. You can create a separate node for users, and store each user using the UID as the key (not necessary though) and the preferences or any other detail as the value. Something like this

```
"root":{
  "users":{
    "UID1":{
      "locations":{
        "location1":true
        "location2":true
      }
    }
    "UID2":{
      "locations":{
        "location2":true
        "location3":true
      }
    }
    "UID3":{
      "locations":{
        "location4":true
        "location5":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can get a reference to each user using

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                   .getReference("users/" + user.getUid() + "/locations");
```

You can pass this reference to a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to get a populate a RecyclerView. However, if the data stored in each list item is small, say just a name and maybe a picture_url, then just store under each user. This may duplicate data but gets the data quickly, which is what a realtime database is supposed to do.

Comment: Great solution to the problem :)  One followup question would be how can i show more info about the location in the RV ? Since i now have a list of locations that the user "follows", should i then get information for each location in the adapter or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: If the information about each location is small, it is advisable to just duplicate it and store it as the value itself. Data is generally stored on the basis of what you want to show on the screen in noSQL databases like the firebase real-time database

Comment: Pr. now when the user clicks on a location it downloads the data from the weather services and pushes data back the firebase Location object . In this way the location list for all users is always updated with the latest data.  Is this possible by using this type of approcach ? (the reason here is speed, i want the user to be able to see the information they need as fast as possible)
PS: tell me of this should be a seperate question.

Comment: Why would you want data from other services stored in a real-time database if you're getting it from the services anyway? I mean if you store the name of a city (for example) in the locations node, you can just get the new data from the weather services Everytime it needs to be shown on screen. Updating the database with it seems pointless

Comment: The idea is that i can at some point in the future update use some backend to send push notifications to the users who has added location X and there is the right conditions at location X. But maybe there is a smarter way of doing this ?

Comment: Then your back end would have to keep probing the weather services for updates right? You can then program your back end to send a notification using FCM. Or if you do it your way your client could decide whether or not a notification should be displayed but that would mean downloading updates from the firebase database Everytime the back end updates it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116972/discussion-between-dukes-and-rohit-navarathna).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see it is by implementing a login functionality. In this way you will know which is the current user.

Then, when you have that functionality, you have two options:

1. Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You must mach the selected locations with the current user and that info will be saved locally on the device. Each time a user logged in, you must check if there are any previously saved data for the current user. **NOTE:** **THIS IS A LAME APPROACH!!!**
2. Implement some kind of a back-end for the app to communicate with. In this way all the info for the locations will be stored on a remote machine and user A will be able to log in from different devices and will see the same info. By using the first approach that won't be possible!